# Knowage installation, database error, mysql

Tags: mysql, centos7

I am trying to install Knowage to my Centos VM in command line and get the following error:

> WARNING: please provide a database user that can create schemas. The
>   following schemas will be created (or overwritten):

- knowage_demo
- foodmart_demo

> JDBC connection failed Database Management System Configuration Use an
>   already installed DBMS [1, Enter]

Select DBMS for metadata:

```
MariaDB [1, Enter]  
MySQL [2]  
2

[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306]

Username: [root]


Password:
```

> WARNING: please provide a database user that can create schemas.

Any ideas on how to make it working? It keeps getting back to this step.

Comment: what user you are trying to connect with?

Comment: I am trying to use root as the user I connect with

Comment: are you able to connect as root directly to the database? with the same credentials you are using here

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly.